# How to set permission for each web part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, visual-web-part

In Attactments(Custom List).

I have three web parts as below picture(web part 1, web part 2, web part 3).

In the case, I create three groups (a group, b group, c group). I want a group who just see web part 1. b group who just see web part 2. c group is same the both.

[image]

Comment: You can set target audiences for each web part from web part properties. Reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open page in edit mode.
- Click on webpart A.
- Click on Webpart properties tab in ribbon.
  [image]
- Go to Target audience in Advance section.

  [image]
- Select Group A in the field
- Click Apply and Okay.
- Repeat same process for next 2 webparts.
- And you are done.

Comment: In my sharepoint. It don't have Target audience in Advance